What are strategies for scaling a 1-bit bitmap for a non-square DPI?
Recently, I've been playing with a pair of dot matrix printers (an Okidata ML186 from the '90s and an IBM Proprinter from the '80s) and have been using them to print both text and bit graphics.
Both printers have a fixed vertical density of 72dpi and a default horizontal density of 60dpi, which is not square. The ESC/P-supporting Oki has a selectable 72x72dpi density—but no such luck on the IBM, which only supports 60, 120, and 240dpi in the horizontal direction.
Are there any good algorithms or recommended best practices for preparing a bit image for a non-square output DPI? With no grayscale available (just on or off), it seems tricky to do effectively.
I have considered, e.g., adding one random pixel (copying its north or south neighbor) for every 5 vertical pixels to "subtly" pad the vertical dimension out to 60dpi; I have also thought about going the other direction and turning every 3 horizontal pixels into 5 in 120dpi mode, which may have better results if adjacent dot skipping is turned on.
Was there a standard way for handling this in the dot matrix RIP days?
